# Black screen on startup after 16.0 to 18.04 update. I am using radeo/intel gpu

Tags: 18.04, radeon, amdgpu, intel-hd

I got a black screen on starting Ubuntu 18.04 after an update.
My GPU is a hybrid Radeon/Intel HD, though Ubuntu uses the Intel(as displayed in terminal).

To fix it, I've tried setting up `grub` to `nomodeset`, but there seems to be no way to fix this.
I can still access the system using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> , but only in command line.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Edit:- the issue is fixed now, it seems like the upgrade was not completed in the first place and all the gui packages weren't installed. I ran sudo `dpkg --configure -a` to complete the installation of remaning packages. Everything's smooth now